# having Google Chrome developer tools open causes pages to not render/load properly

Tags: google-chrome

I cannot find anyone else who is affected by this bug, so I am reluctant to believe it is actually a bug with google chrome.

To better understand what I am dealing with here I have created a short video of what is happening.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMHBj_K8upY

It appears Javascript is not executed while the developer tools are open however I cannot be certain that is the only issue.

I have un-installed google chrome and chromium and removed their associated folders in the `~/.cache` directory. Then re-installed chrome using `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable` however the problem persists.

Any help tracking down why this is happening and how I might circumvent it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 with Chrome dev 17. What is that showing up in the console's call stack? Looks like there's some breakpoint set up. (You can see it's the console stopping the code from executing because of the play like button and the 'Paused' written in the right window)

Try looking at all the breakpoints and making sure none of them are ticked?

Comment: Most likely, it'll be the `load` breakpoint, under `Event Listener Breakpoints`.

Comment: @Amaan Thankyou! you made me re-look at the console and I noticed I had pause on all exceptions enabled. Duhhh! Hard to see that little blue guy down there.

Comment: Sure. I think you should add what solved it as an answer and mark it for the Googlers who may come here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It doesn't fit the site, it was a configuration mistake on my end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## My Bad!

It appears I had `Pause on all exceptions` enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly you simply have javascript disabled via the developer tools. When the developer tools are not open, javascript will execute, but if you have the 'disable javascript' checkbox checked in developer tools, the page may not be properly rendering when you open developer tools.

To re-enable Javascript, In Google Chrome Console:
Click on the settings icon (right side)

Settings > General

Uncheck "Disable Javascript"

Comment: This doesn't at all answer the question. Are you in the right thread?

Comment: rlemon, I had the same problem, when I open the console, the page doesn't works properly, and if I close the Google Developer Tool, the page backs to run as expected. I fix it as I've learned in your topic (I created this account just to instruct other persons with same problem, starting the point I find out your topic from Google search)

Comment: well having JS disabled vs pausing is probably not really related. and in fairness this entire question doesn't really belong here (I asked it/and answered it a while ago when I was a bit newer) . If anything it *could* be asked on SuperUser.. but has nothing to do with Ubuntu (and is not specific to Ubuntu).

Comment: really it is not specfic to Ubuntu, and I also think you vote down my answer by mistake because your self question is not in the right thread. I did a favor to you and other users and you come give me a sermon, c'mon

Comment: I voted yours down because it doesn't solve the original issue and I voted to close my original issue as I cannot delete it because it has answers. This entire thread is not useful on AskUbuntu for the reasons I stated above.

Comment: FWIW this answer was what I needed. I'm glad you couldnt delete the question (or this answer).